# intel graphics screen stuck

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Edit: crossposted to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747726/intel-graphics-stuck

I have a laptop with intel integrated graphics and an nvidia
graphics card.  From time to time, if there is a sudden change to the
screen, the screen will get stuck in the previous state. It will stay
in this state until i change the screen again, e.g I move down a page
in a pdf, the screen stays in the state before the movement and will
only fully turn the page if i jiggle the page up and down again.

I blacklisted the nouveau driver in /etc/modprobe.d/ and `sudo lshw -c video` shows that the nvidia card does not have a driver currently so
i assume it is not being used but the problem still persists, so i do
not think the nvidia driver is responsible. Any help would be
appreciated.

Edit: I am using ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I am using a HP envy laptop.

Comment: Try: Open Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers, and install the available NVidia driver. Reboot

Comment: I have tried using the latest driver. The problem here appears to still be happening whilst the nvidia driver is inactive.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS and the make/model of the computer that you're running (this will help others if they have similar issues in the future). Thanks